# Outlook : Get unread emails

Tags: delphi, outlook

I am using Outlook in my app. To have the number of unread mails, I use "UnreadItemCount".
To have the number of unread mails, I use:

```
   Inbox: MAPIFolder;
   NewMail: boolean;
   Item: TListItem;

  outlook, NameSpace , aMailItem : OLEVariant;
  i : integer;

const
  olFolderInbox = $00000006;
begin

OutlookApplication1.CreateObject('Outlook.Application');
NmSpace := OutlookApplication1.GetNameSpace('MAPI');
NmSpace.Logon('', '', False, False);

Inbox := NmSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox);
NewMail := (Inbox.UnreadItemCount > 0);
ShowMessage('Number of unread emails: ' + inttostr(Inbox.UnreadItemCount));
```

I want to have **unread emails**. That is, the list of emails with the property **Unread** or: **UnRead = true**.
is there a way to do this please?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What have you done yourself so far? Please show your code. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Call `MAPIFolder.Items.Restrict` (returns Items collection) with a query like `[Unread] = true`

Comment: I used the property: InboxFolder.Items.Restrict ('[UnRead] = FALSE')    
I want to test if the email has been read or not. If it has been read, a text is added to ListView1:        "Email Read". Here is my code:                `if ItemsToProcess = InboxFolder.Items.Restrict('[UnRead]=FALSE') then begin                  
   MaListe := ListView1.Items.Add;    
   MaListe.Caption := 'Mail Read' ;  
   MaListe.SubItems.Add(ListView1.Items.Add.SubItems[3]) ;`  .       The problem is that in ListView1, the text ("Email Read") is not added. What is my error please?

Comment: I am not sure what that code does you are comparing an Items object with a brand new Items object returned by Restrict. Of course the two are not the same. But why would you even do that?

Comment: I am making my debut with Outlook. It's a bit difficult for me now. I am making my debut with Outlook. It's a bit difficult for me now.
Let me explain: I load the emails from Outlook into a TListView, then I want to test if the email has been read or not. If it has been read, a text is added to ListView1: "Email Read" in Column. Please, how do I do what I want?

Comment: When you loop through the items collection, test the `MailItem.Unread` property. But since you request only unread emails, that test doesn't buy you match - you already know the value of the Unread property.

Comment: I fixed my error: `InboxFolder.Items.Item (i) as MailItem;`   I had corrected two different things.
Thanks for your help Dmitry

Comment: Why do you still loop through *all* items if you already retrieved a restricted collection from Items.Restrict?